# Why does this regular expression hang the browser?

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I'm trying to debug a strange issue which hangs Chrome and Firefox (not Safari though).

I've boiled it down to this code (which is from a 3rd party, but my code is interacting with it):

```
var str = 'pymxPYMxau-trade-in-calculator-1xPYMxheightxPYMx950'; // String is coming from a dynamic object, but this is the value that gets passed to the pattern matching

var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
        '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
        '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
        '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
        '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
        '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator

pattern.test(str); // This line hangs the browser
```

***ATTENTION: Try this code at your own risk, it hangs Chrome!***

What is going on here?

Comment: I get Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
@debugger eval code:10:13 in Firefox

Comment: There is something in your regex creation because it seems to work fine in regex101 https://regex101.com/r/89XZGa/2/

Comment: The domain name part looks like an invitation to regex DoS. you have `([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*` which opens up a wide range of possibilites -- nesting unlimited quantifiers is usually not a good idea. Try `([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])?)\\.)`

Comment: @jcubic You missed the `i` flag and the escapes before `d`, [here is the correct one](https://regex101.com/r/89XZGa/3). The `[a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*` part is killing it, you should use `[a-z\\d][a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d]` or [`[a-z\\d](?:[a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])?`](https://regex101.com/r/0AA0xE/1) instead.

Comment: I suspected the regex to be the fault here, however I do not have direct control to change it. I will flag it to the website owner where I saw this.